# Why curl do not downloading the picture?

Tags: bash, curl

```
    echo -e "url : $rnd_photo_medium_url" #this showing perfect result in the terminal
    echo -e "photo name : $rnd_photo_original_name" #this also perfect in the terminal
    #set variable
    rnd_photo_medium_url="$rnd_photo_medium_url"
    rnd_photo_original_name="$rnd_photo_original_name"
    
    #download photo
    curl "$rnd_photo_medium_url" > "$rnd_photo_original_name" #This not working
    curl $rnd_photo_medium_url > $rnd_photo_original_name # This not works 
    curl "$rnd_photo_medium_url" > $rnd_photo_original_name #This not works
    
    curl "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6775289/pexels-photo-6775289.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" > 6775294.jpeg #This works 
    the result:
    `url : "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2449605/pexels-photo-2449605.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"

photo name : 5635125.jpeg
```

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "https
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "https
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "https
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11377  100 11377    0     0  11099      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 11099
`

But from terminal it works fine

```
 curl "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6775289/pexels-photo-6775289.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" > 6775294.jpeg
```

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 11377  100 11377    0     0  20536      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 20536`

Why  it is not working inside of the script?

I think **double quote** is not a matter

Edit : removing photos

Comment: you need to use double quotes in curl command for the variable.Eg `curl "$rnd_photo_medium_url"`

Comment: @P....Actually I have tried by it but also not worked.

Comment: Please format multiline code blocks as such

Comment: @baponkar You put the quotes *in* the value of the parameter; you did not note the parameter expansion. `foo='"..."'; curl $foo` and `foo="..."; curl "$foo"` are *very* different.

Comment: Please copy-paste your terminal command into your script to convince yourself that there is no difference between in-script and out-of-script. The problem is instead that your URL contains double quotes and `"https` is not a valid protocol (but `https` is)

Comment: I have tried to put `curl https://images.pexels.com/photos/68704/pexels-photo-68704.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350 --output 1766215.jpeg` inside of script file not works showing `Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.`@chepner @that other guy

Comment: @baponkar This is not the same command that your post says worked fine in the terminal.

Comment: even I have been tried with `feh <url>` inside of the script but not load the picture.

Comment: You are confusing quotes in values with quotes in syntax. For example, `echo "Hello"` outputs `Hello` and NOT `"Hello"`. It's ok for the command to contains quotes, but not for the value to contain quotes. If you want to reproduce the failure in a terminal, you can use `curl '"https://images.pexels.com/photos/6775289/pexels-photo-6775289.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"' > 6775294.jpeg`. Please note that this must be copy-pasted accurately. Any modifications or adaptations of the command will change the meaning and therefore the result.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: That said, this looks like you have literal quotes when you need to have syntactic ones (which is what that other guy said just above). Adding quotes to your data does not substitute for quotes that are missing from your code!

Comment: (And copying-and-pasting strings _with literal quotes_ to your shell command line means that they're parsed as shell source code, so they then become _syntactic_ quotes, which is why it works only when you copy-and-paste to an interactive command line but not in the script!)

Comment: ...so, to have a [mre], we need code that shows how you assign the variable `rnd_photo_medium_url`. (Code! Not a photo or a screenshot! Something we can copy-and-paste to run ourselves and get the same result; otherwise, answers can't be tested).

Comment: `rnd_photo_medium_url`  value showing correct result in the terminal  I

Comment: No, it's **not** correct output shown in the terminal. In the terminal it shows literal quotes. Those literal quotes are wrong.

Comment: `echo "something"` only writes `something`, not `"something"`. The fact that `echo` writes `"http://..."` instead of `http://...` means your URL has literal quotes in it. **Those quotes are wrong and you need to get them out of your data.**

Comment: To figure out _how_ to get them out of the data, we need to know how you're getting the URL _into_ the variable. For example, if you get it from `jq`, then you may need to use the `-r` argument to get a raw output string instead of a string formatted as JSON syntax -- that's just one example of a possible fix, we'd need to see how the variable is set to provide a sure example of how to fix it.

Comment: To repeat what what you've already been told numerous times yet again: `echo -e "url : $rnd_photo_medium_url"` is **not** showing a perfect result in the terminal. It would be perfect only if it showed `https://images.pexels.com/photos/6775289/pexels-photo-6775289.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350` **with no quotes**. The quotes are incorrectly sent to `curl` for the same reason they're incorrectly sent to `echo`, so curl thinks you have a `"https://` URL instead of a `https://` URL, and `"https` is not a valid URL scheme so it fails.

Comment: (It works with quotes on the command line because when given in an unquoted context on the command line the quotes are syntactic, not literal; I've already repeated the difference several times, so I won't do so again here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffyThank you gotcha

Comment: (BTW, I strongly recommend against using `echo -e`; for an in-depth discussion, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo over at [unix.se]; in cases where `-e` makes a difference you should be using `printf` instead; when there isn't a need for `-e`, you can just use `echo` without it and have more reliable behavior).